# using mixin with a def

Tags: django, mixins

I m using this Accessmixin on generic.views:

```
class OrganisorAndLoginRequiredMixin(AccessMixin):
    """Verify that the current user is authenticated and is an organisor."""
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated or not request.user.is_organisor:
            return redirect("home")
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I want to use it on a def. I tried this but I've error bellow.

```
@OrganisorAndLoginRequiredMixin()
def AgentUpdateView(request, pk):
    obj = Agent.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
    if obj is None:
        return render(request, "404.html", {
            "Instance": pk
        })
    else:
        form = AgentModelForm(instance=obj.user)
```

Error:
TypeError: 'OrganisorAndLoginRequiredMixin' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [class based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) for that:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView


class AgentUpdateView(OrganisorAndLoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Agent
    template_name = 'template.html'
    form_class = AgentModelForm
```